# Inherit function type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, kotlin-function-type

Is there a way in Kotlin to inherit function types?
What I want is to have a member like so: `private lateinit var onPickedFunc: (Any) -> Task<Void>?` so I can dynamically store the functions I need to run after a user has made it's choice. For example:

```
private fun showImagePicker(func: (Uri) -> Task<Void>?) {
        onPickedFunc = func
        val intent =
            Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            )
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_PICK_IMAGE)
    }

private fun showMenu(func: (Context) -> Task<Void>?, v: View) {
        onPickedFunc = func
        PopupMenu(context, v).apply {
            // ProfileFragment implements OnMenuItemClickListener
            setOnMenuItemClickListener(this@ProfileFragment)
            inflate(R.menu.profile_settings_menu)
            show()
        }
    }
```

I did find a group of classes called `Function`, but none of them allow inheritance in the input parameter (one of them allows inheritance in the output parameter: `Function<out R>`).
Is there any way to achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: How this is supposed to be realized in the interface? User is typing code of kotlin lambda himself? Or user is selecting one of possible predefined options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is one of variance.

`func` is a function whose parameter is declared as a `Uri`.

But your `onPickedFunc` property would be a function whose parameter can be *anything*.  You should be able to call it with an `Int`, or a `Uri`, or a `String`, or any other non-null value.

So you can't assign `func` to it, because that (probably) wouldn't be able to handle an `Int` or a `String` or whatever.

In technical terms, the types aren't compatible.  Function parameters have `in` variance (contravariance); to be a subtype, it must accept a supertype of each parameter.  (This is the reverse of the function's return type, which has `out` variance AKA covariance.)  So the compiler would flag up a type mismatch.

If you want to store your `(Uri) -> Task<Void>` function in a property, it would have to be of type `(Uri) -> Task<Void>` or some supertype, which means the function would have to accept a `Uri` or some *subtype*.

(I don't know what type your `Uri` is, but if it were `final`, like `java.net.URI`, then the only subtype would be `Uri` itself.)

---

By the way, the  `kotlin.jvm.functions.Function…` interfaces are an implementation detail; the compiler uses them to implement function types on the JVM, but they're not something you should refer to in code (except in special cases such as reflection, I think).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and for the explanation! I understand now why having `Any` as the parameter type is problematic. I would still like to avoid having a member for each possible follow up function. Is there a logical way to define a property as a "function getting one param of any type"? So I will be able to cast it to it's subtype "function getting one `Uri` param" before calling it in my `onActivityResult`, and cast it to it's subtype "function getting one `Context` param" in my `onMenuItemClick` and so on... Or do you have any other suggestion to solve this neatly? Thanks:)

Comment: If you have some other way of knowing what parameter type it will accept, you could store it as `(Nothing) -> Task<Void>`, since [Nothing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) is a subtype of every type. You couldn't call it directly, as it has no instances, but you could upcast it to the particular type before calling it. (In other situations, you can use the [star projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) `*` to mean ‘some specific type we don't know here’, but that doesn't work here.)

Comment: I've tried that first thing when I read your answer but when I try to cast it: `(onPickedFunc as ((Uri) -> Task<Void>?))` I get "Unchecked cast: (Nothing) -> Task<Void>? to (Uri) -> Task<Void>?" warning, and when I try to check it: `(onPickedFunc is ((Uri) -> Task<Void>?))` I get "Cannot check for instance of erased type: (Uri) -> Task<Void>?" error.

Comment: Yes, you'll get ‘Unchecked cast’, but that's only a warning: it tells you that the compiler can't be sure it's safe, so it's up to you to make sure.  You won't be able to check the `Void` part — as the other warning says, that's a generic type which is erased at runtime.  You'll be able to check the rest, though — and if you can tell from the rest of the code that the parameter is _always_ `Void`, then you can ignore the warning.